# Migration Approach for BT2006 R2 to BT2013 R2

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-2013r2

Currently I am working on Migrating BT2006 R2 (VS2005) to BT2013 R2 (VS2013).
I tried below twp approaches.

**Approach I:**

1. First, Open the BT2006 R2 Project in (VS2010)[BT2010] [Intermediate]
2. then Upgrade BT2010 Project to BT2013 R2 (opening in VS2013 Project). It's work fine. there is no issue on that.

**Approach II:**

1. Directly open the BT2006R2 Project Solution file in VS2013 (without Intermediate version)
2. Getting the below error

   > Error migrating project user file. The element BIZTALK beneath element VisualStudioProject is unrecognized.

I tried to remove project user file and then migrate to BT2013 R2. but still same error occurred.

So it means, we can't we do direct migration from BT2006 R2 to BT2013 R2?

Do we always need to do the first approach above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it this way, if the direct upgrade does not work, you have to use the intermediate step.  That's it.

So, yes, you must follow Approach 1.